# Adding error to tree height data using gaussian

Tags: r, gaussian, noise

I have some tree heights which I would like to add a Gaussian error of 5% to the tree heights. I was wondering if I'm using the correct code with this;

```
Tree heights<-c(20.1,25.3,33.7,17.5,39.6)

Treeheight*rnorm(length(Treeheight),mean=1,sd = 0.05)
```

The results of this code is;

19.31566 26.85645 33.42292 17.91047 38.05132

Im trying to replicate a study where - "The random error ε of tree height was presumed to be normally distributed ε ~ N(μ, σ2). These errors were generated by adding a Gaussian error term with mean μ and standard deviation σ to the particular error component." They then apply 5%,10% and 15% to the tree heights

Is this correct way to add a percentage gaussian error? For some reason I keep doubting myself.

Many thanks for any help!!

Guy

Comment: Could you explain further? Here `R` would just be a way to do it. But first you need to know exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Hello, Im trying to replicate a study where - "The random error ε of tree height was presumed to be normally distributed ε ~ N(μ, σ2). These errors were generated by adding a Gaussian error term with mean μ and standard deviation σ to the particular error component." They then apply 5%,10% and 15% to the tree heights

Comment: Feel free to post the ref to the study.

Comment: Effects of Individual Tree Detection Error Sources on Forest Management
Planning Calculations, 
Mikko Vastaranta,  Remote Sensing · December 2011